Reference for probabilities of maximum of a random walk with drift
Let $X_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and set $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for $n > 0$. Let $S_0 := X_0$. In the situation I’m thinking of, $X_i = a > 0$ with probability $\frac12$ and equals $b < 0$ with probability $\frac12$, so let’s specialize to that. Let’s assume $|b|>a$, so that this process can be modeled as a random walk with negative drift $\mu$ and equal step size $\sigma$. Then Allan Gut’s textbook Stopped Random Walks says the maximum $M=\max_n S_n$ exists a.s. and $P(M=0)>0$.
I want to know if there are any formulas for $P(M\geq c)$ as a function of $c$, $\sigma$ and $\mu$. If this were a Wiener process the analysis would be easier, but here you have to worry about overshooting.
